# How to run a command in background using ssh and detach the session

Tags: shell, ssh, nohup

I'm currently trying to ssh into a remote machine and run a script, then leave the node with the script running. Below is my script. However, when it runs, the script is successfully run on the machine but ssh session hangs. What's the problem?

```
ssh -x $username@$node 'rm -rf statuslist
                        mkdir statuslist
                        chmod u+x ~/monitor/concat.sh
                        chmod u+x ~/monitor/script.sh
                        nohup ./monitor/concat.sh &
                        exit;'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are some situations when you want to execute/start some scripts on a remote machine/server (which will terminate automatically) and disconnect from the server.

eg: A script running on a box which when executed

1. takes a model and copies it to a remote server
2. creates a script for running a simulation with the model and push it to server
3. starts the script on the server and disconnect
4. The duty of the script thus started is to run the simulation in the server and once completed (will take days to complete) copy the results back to client.

I would use the following command:

```
ssh remoteserver 'nohup /path/to/script `</dev/null` >nohup.out 2>&1 &'
```

@CKeven, you may put all those commands on one script, push it to the remote server and initiate it as follows:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash  
rm -rf statuslist  
mkdir statuslist  
chmod u+x ~/monitor/concat.sh  
chmod u+x ~/monitor/script.sh  
nohup ./monitor/concat.sh &  
' > script.sh

chmod u+x script.sh

rsync -azvp script.sh remotehost:/tmp

ssh remotehost '/tmp/script.sh `</dev/null` >nohup.out 2>&1 &'
```

Hope this works ;-)

Edit:
You can also use
ssh user@host 'screen -S SessionName -d -m "/path/to/executable"'

Which creates a detached screen session and runs target command within it

Comment: What if the command you are running requires input from a file (such as a large db import, e.g. mysql < dump.sql)? How do you accomplish the </dev/null if you need to redirect a file there instead?

Comment: If you monitor ```ps -ef | grep ssh```, this process keeps running. If I kill it with ```-9``` thats perfectly fine, the remote process still keeps running. Is there any way to not keep this process running on my local, and only keep the one on remote alive. I have tried removing the > nohup.out but it pipes the output to stdout. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22):

What do you think about using `screen` for this?  You could run `screen` via ssh to start the command (`concat.sh`) and then you'd be able to return to the screen session if you wanted to monitor it (could be handy, depending on what concat does).

To be more specific, try this:

```
ssh -t $username@$node screen -dm -S testing ./monitor/concat.sh
```

You should find that the prompt returns immediately, and that `concat.sh` is running on the remote machine.  I'll explain some of the options:

- `ssh -t` makes a TTY.  screen needs this.
- `screen -dm` makes it start in "detached" mode.  This is like "background" for your purposes.
- `-S` testing gives your screen session a name.  It is optional but recommended.

Now, once you've done this, you can go to the remote machine and run this:

```
screen -r testing
```

This will attach you to the screen session which contains your program.  From there you can control it, kill it, see its output, and so on.  Ctrl-A, then d will detach you from the screen session.  `screen -ls` will list all running sessions.

Comment: @John Zwinck, did this definitely work for you? The following command does not work for me: ssh -t HOST "screen -dm -S sleep sleep 10". It simply says "Connection to HOST closed" and when I login to the server there are no detached screens.

Comment: @richardkmiller: When I tried it just now I got the same (bad) result you did.  I changed the `-t` option to ssh to be `-f` instead, so that it backgrounds the command (and does not allocate a TTY), and then it worked.  I suspect something changed in the intervening 2+ years of Linux since I wrote this answer...try `ssh -f HOST "screen -dm -S sleep sleep 10"` and you may find it works now.

Answer (score 4):

It could be the standard input stream. Try `ssh -n ...` or `ssh -f ...`.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. `ssh -f "user@host DISPLAY=myhost:0.0  qtcreator &"`

Answer (score 0):

For me, only this worked:

```
screen -dmS name sh my-script.sh
```

This, of course, depends on screen, and lets you attach later, if you ever want stdin or stdout. Screen will terminate itself when my-script.sh ends.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a much more common decision that required some efforts to find, and it really works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
theScreenSessionName="test"
theTabNumber="1"
theStuff="date; hostname; cd /usr/local; pwd; /usr/local/bin/top"

echo "this is a test"

ssh -f user@server "/usr/local/bin/screen -x $theScreenSessionName -p $theTabNumber -X stuff \" 
$theStuff
\""
```

It sends $theStuff list of commands to the tab No $theTabNumber of the screen session $theScreenSessionName preliminarily created at the 'server' on behalf of 'user'.

Please be aware of a trailing whitespace after
-X stuff \"
that is sent to overcome a 'stuff' option's glitch. The whitespace and $theStuff in the next line are appended by 'Enter' (^M) keystrokes. DON'T MISS 'EM!

The "this is a test" message is echoed in the initial terminal, and $theStuff commands are really executed inside the mentioned screen/tab.