# Run two java programs in a bash script after ssh

Tags: java, bash, shell, ssh, nohup

In my script I SSHed a host and tried to run two java programs. The first java program runs with nohup and & at  the end. After that I try to run another java program but it gives syntax error. I guess it has something to do with the &. I do not want to ssh again.

```
ssh $host "nohup java -cp daemon.jar:. runtime.daemon.MPJDaemon >>/logs/$host-wrapper.log 2>&1 &;java Health"
```

It gives
    bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;

Any ideas

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run a command in background using ssh and detach the session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628204/how-to-run-a-command-in-background-using-ssh-and-detach-the-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, `&` implies semicolon (`;`), so you don't really need that semicolon after the ampersand

From http://hacktux.com/man/bash

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell.