# How can I connect to a remote host with `ssh`, start a `screen` session on that host, and run a command in that session, with a bash script?

Tags: bash

#### The Problem

I have a command that takes a very long time to run, so I usually run it from a detached `screen` session on my remote so that it keeps running if I close my local terminal. I decided to write a bash script to automate this process so that it does the following in sequence:

1. Connect to the remote host with `ssh`
2. Start a detached `screen` session
3. Run a long command in that `screen` session

##### Notes

- The command is a `sudo` command stored in a string variable named `cmd`
- `cmd` is technically several commands separated by `;` and is a very long string
- When running the command, the `screen` session must be attached to get user credentials

### Notable Attempts

##### (Best yet) Directly connecting and sending the command, attempting to detach later

```bash
ssh -t <host> "screen bash -c '$cmd'"
```

This command connects to the remote host, starts a screen session and runs the command, but the session is not detached. As soon as the command finishes running, the session terminates. I'm getting the same behavior running `screen -d` or `C-a d` to detach while the session is active.

##### Connecting, creating a detached session but not attaching, and sending the command with `stuff`

```bash
ssh <host> "screen -dmS <session-name>; screen -r <session-name> -X stuff '$cmd^M'"
```

The above successfully connects to the remote host and starts a detached screen session, but the `stuff` command does not work with `cmd` in this case because it is too long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a command in background using ssh and detach the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628204/how-to-run-a-command-in-background-using-ssh-and-detach-the-session)

Comment: @Nic3500 Not really; I want to run cmd, which is an inline bash command, not an executable. As for the command syntax itself, replacing the executable with "$cmd" does not work.